# Cannot load image of workspace

Tags: rstudio

I have problem that I cant load image of my workspace to my RStudio. When I use command load data nothing happened. If i check it with file exists output is false but I can see the file with my own eyes. I have the right working directory and I load file with right name. I checked it many times. I dont know what is the problem.I tried load it manualy and this happened.

[here you can see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHtYn.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a definitive answer but here are some things you can try:

- 1st, Ensure that for SURE you are in the folder where you think you are: in your screenshot, the Windows explorer is opened to `C:/Users/mates/OneDrive/Desktop/BC` whereas the RStudio `getwd()` command returns `C:/Users/mates/OneDrive/Pocitac/Desktop/BC` (I am unable to type the correct path here due to the non-ascii characters, but I could have copy-pasted it if it wasn't a screenshot :p). You can use the `list.files()` command ([see doc](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/list.files)) to check whether the file *does* exist in the folder you are using .
- 2d, try that in a folder that's not synchronized by OneDrive and see whether that's the issue
- 3d, try that in a folder that has only ascii characters in it's path: it could be a [bug due to the non-ascii characters in the file path](https://community.rstudio.com/t/rstudio-cant-deal-with-file-names-with-unicode-characters/126601/6)